# Переменные окружения внутри контейнера при exec

Tags: linux, docker

Хочу запустить команду вне контейнера через `exec`, которая выполнялось бы соответственно внутри контейнера. Команда запускает `cmake`, который использует переменные окружения, которые объявлены уже при создании образа контейнера.

Если я в самом контейнере и выполняю `env`, он мне выдает список всех переменных которые мне нужны.

```
root@74b9b0dbbbc9:/# env
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/:
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
HOSTNAME=74b9b0dbbbc9
QT_SELECT=qt5
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
PWD=/
HOME=/root
CXX=/usr/bin/g++
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
_=/usr/bin/env
```

А если я выполняю `dev@local:~/docker$ sudo docker exec -it dever bash -c 'env'`

```
HOSTNAME=74b9b0dbbbc9
PWD=/
HOME=/root
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
```

В чем причина?

И можно ли через exec (или run) выполнить набор команд с переменными, которые уже заданы?

Comment: в том, что переменные окружения — это свойство процесса (которое он может передать порождённому процессу).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin дополнил вопрос. Есть ли способ выполнять какую-либо команду внутри контейнера с заданным окружением? Переменные прописаны в `/root/.bashrc` .